# цикл for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы, for

Народ начал изучать JS, надо решить такую задачу:

Напишите цикл, который за 7 вызовов console.log выводит такой треугольник:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

Не понимаю почему мой код не работает

```js
function f1() { //создал функцию
  for (var pk = "#"; pk.length < 8; pk += "#";) { //создал переменною pk, написал условие - если длинна переменной pk меньше 8 то надо присвоить переменной pk +1 символ # 
    console.log(pk); //вывел значение переменной в консоль
  };
```

что я сделал не так?

Не судите строго, я новичок в JS :).

Comment: Уберите `;` после `pk += "#"`. В консоли, кстати, ошибка эта показывается: _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"_. А, и `}` одной в конце не хватает

Comment: Нет закрывающей кавычки у функции, и лишняя точка с запятой в цикле for

Answer (score 1):

У вас сразу две ошибки.

1. После последнего выражения не нужно ставить `;`
2. Вы пропустили закрывающую скобку `}` функции f1

```js
function f1() {
  for (var pk = "#"; pk.length < 8; pk += "#") {
    console.log(pk);
  }
}
f1();
```